# Objective C - Caught exception causes crash

Tags: objective-c, exception, crash, uncaught-exception

I'm doing some Objective C tests. I'm raising a custom exception with this code:

```
- (double)foo:(int)x{
   if (x == 0){
      [NSException raise:@"InvalidX" format:@"X can't be 0"];
   }
   return 1/x;
}
```

and catching it with this code:

```
@try {
   double y = [self foo:0];
} @catch (NSException *e) {
   return;
}
```

It works good if i run the application in XCode but it crashes when i run the .app:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
objc[1769]: garbage collection is OFF
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidX', reason: 'X can't be 0'
*** First throw call stack:
```

It doesn't look "uncaught"! I can't explain this

Comment: Are you sure you run the up-to-date executable outside Xcode?

Comment: Yes, i am. I'm creating the executable with Product -> Archive -> Share -> Application

Comment: Returning out of an exception handler is a bad idea in the first place